# How to create a shared subscription using spring JMS

Tags: java, jboss, jms, spring-jms, jms-topic

JMS 2.0 specification introduced the concept of shared durable subscriptions. I have a use case where I have to create subscriptions programmatically upon server start up. We have clustered JBoss servers. Hence each JBoss will have similar configurations and every JBoss will have applications which will create durable subscribers(messaging provider is WMQ). Since durable subscriptions have to have a unique name, I thought of using shared subscriptions. Now the problem is that spring's 4.0.6.RELEASE has support for new features in JMS 2.0, however I did not find a way to create shared durable subscriptions via spring. We use spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer to create the listeners. Am I doing it right? I appreciate any suggestions that you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature will be available as from Spring 4.1.RC2 that will be released today. A new `destination-type` will be available called `sharedDurableTopic`, check [the current build of the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Turns out WMQ does not have support for JMS 2.0. WMQ version 8.0 has that support